# Animate toggle visibility with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am toggling my  Div's with the following code, but cant figure out if and how to animate it. Any help would be appreciated.

The link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('example'); return false;"></a>
```

The script:

```
<script>

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? If so, try `.animate()`. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) but I don't see any. In pure JS you'll have too much trouble for achieving this.

Try using [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    $("#" + id).toggle('slow');
}
```

Besides, I would suggest you a better use of jQuery:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="example"></a>
```

The code above is using a [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which combinated with event binding could make you code much clearer:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[data-toggle]').on("click", function()
    {
        toggle_visibility($(this).data("toggle"));
    }
});
```

Now all your links with `data-toggle` have the same behaviour.

Comment: ~Thanx for this tip

Answer (score 2):

rolling with DontVoteMeDown's pattern:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   $("#" + id).slideDown("slow"); /* replace this with any of the following */
}
```

or

```
$("#" + id).fadeIn(500);
```

or

```
$("#" + id).fadeOut(500);
```

or

```
$("#" + id).toggle(500);
```

For more complex animations you can use easing as well. http://easings.net/
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, **easing** ] [, complete ] )